# Gravity form after submission

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

How to use gform_after_submission in gravity forms? When form is submit or after submission I want to display a modal.

Answer (score 0):

in your function.php you need to do something like this:

```
add_action("gform_after_submission_{your_form_id}", "{function_name}_{your_form_id}",10, 2 );
function {function_name}_{your_form_id}($entry, $form){
/*
* Your code goes here
*/
}
```

Comment: this is what I did it's not working..
`add_action("gform_after_submission_1", "openmodal_1",10, 2 );
function openmodal_1($entry, $form){
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).load(function(){
     $('.modal-trigger').click();
    });
  });
}`

Comment: basically what is the aim of this javascript?

Answer (score 0):

There are examples of use in Gravity Forms documentation.

The code should be placed in the functions.php file of your active theme.

Here is the code to send data to third-party:

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission', 'post_to_third_party', 10, 2 );
function post_to_third_party( $entry, $form ) {

 $post_url = 'http://thirdparty.com';
 $body = array(
    'first_name' => rgar( $entry, '1.3' ),
    'last_name' => rgar( $entry, '1.6' ),
    'message' => rgar( $entry, '3' ),
    );
 GFCommon::log_debug( 'gform_after_submission: body => ' . print_r( $body, true ) );

 $request = new WP_Http();
 $response = $request->post( $post_url, array( 'body' => $body ) );
 GFCommon::log_debug( 'gform_after_submission: response => ' . print_r( $response, true ) );
}
```

I think, you are able to send it like this to jquery that will create modal from the data.

Like this, you are able to select form by id: ( form_id = 1 in example)

```
 add_action( 'gform_after_submission_1', 'post_to_third_party', 10, 2 );
```

source:
https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_after_submission/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20269149)

Comment: Thank you @MatheusLacerda , I made effort to correct it.